# Timeout Exception while using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exception, timeout

So I'm trying to upload a huge collection of NFTs using a .py file that i've found on Github,it is using selenium to bulk everthing, but whenever I run the code I get the next error on the bash:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Loula\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Loula\Downloads\NFTs-Upload-to-OpenSea-main\openseaupload.py", line 137, in main_program_loop
    wait_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/span/a')
  File "C:\Users\Loula\Downloads\NFTs-Upload-to-OpenSea-main\openseaupload.py", line 129, in wait_xpath
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, code)))
  File "C:\Users\Loula\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Since I have never used selenium but I do understand some python,I have been researching and I have seen that I had to change the timings,I have done it but it still doesn't work.what else can I try?
PS: this is the github(https://github.com/nftdevs/NFTs-Upload-to-OpenSea/) so you can check the code.
Many thanks :D

Update:I think the error can be here while opening the chrome browser.

```
  opt = Options()
    opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=project_path + "/chromedriver.exe",
        chrome_options=opt,
    )
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    ###wait for methods
    def wait_css_selector(code):
        wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, code))
        )
        
    def wait_css_selectorTest(code):
        wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, code))
        )    
    def wait_xpath(code):
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, code)))
    while end_num >= start_num:
        print("Start creating NFT " +  loop_title + str(start_num))
        driver.get(collection_link)
        # time.sleep(3)
        wait_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/span/a')
        additem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/span/a')
        additem.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        wait_xpath('//*[@id="media"]')
        imageUpload = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="media"]')
        imagePath = os.path.abspath(file_path + "\\" + str(start_num) + "." + loop_file_format)  # change folder here
        imageUpload.send_keys(imagePath)
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="name"]')
        name.send_keys(loop_title + str(start_num))  # +1000 for other folders #change name before "#"
        time.sleep(0.5)
        ext_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="external_link"]')
        ext_link.send_keys(loop_external_link)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        desc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="description"]')
        desc.send_keys(loop_description)
        time.sleep(0.5)
``
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based code from the github.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution mentioned below:

change this line of code

```
def wait_xpath(code):
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, code)))
```

With this

```
def wait_xpath(code):
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, code))
```

So the working solution for this will be like

```
opt = Options()
    opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=project_path + "/chromedriver.exe",
        chrome_options=opt,
    )
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    ###wait for methods
    def wait_css_selector(code):
        wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, code))
        )
        
    def wait_css_selectorTest(code):
        wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, code))
        )    
     def wait_xpath(code):
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, code))

    while end_num >= start_num:
        print("Start creating NFT " +  loop_title + str(start_num))
        driver.get(collection_link)
        # time.sleep(3)
        wait_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/span/a')
        additem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/span/a')
        additem.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        wait_xpath('//*[@id="media"]')
        imageUpload = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="media"]')
        imagePath = os.path.abspath(file_path + "\\" + str(start_num) + "." + loop_file_format)  # change folder here
        imageUpload.send_keys(imagePath)
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="name"]')
        name.send_keys(loop_title + str(start_num))  # +1000 for other folders #change name before "#"
        time.sleep(0.5)
        ext_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="external_link"]')
        ext_link.send_keys(loop_external_link)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        desc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="description"]')
        desc.send_keys(loop_description)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

You can see more about [*wait_for_element_to_be_clickable*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)